# Different content-type and header responses in openapi 3.1.0

Tags: openapi

I have an endpoint that can return different 200 success responses. Each response is a different content-type with different headers.

Every example I see online of 'different responses' only demonstration the basic example of the same content-type with a different content structure, like different JSON objects.

`OneOf` doesn't work because the responses aren't a complete schema. I cannot rename the response HTTP codes or append anything like `200-image-response`

```json
"/download-content": {
  "get": {
    "responses": {
      200: { // doesn't work
        "oneOf": [ 
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/200-image-response"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/responses/200-video-response"
          }
        ]
      },
      500: { // completely fine
        "$ref": "#/components/responses/500"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have already had to use work-arounds in other places in my contract due to limitations of openapi, but I am not sure how I can create a work-around in this case since the endpoint won't change nor will any request headers.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, you can't use the `oneOf` schema keyword directly under a `response` object.

You need something like

```yaml
responses:
  '200':
    description: OK
    content:
       'image/jpeg':
         schema:
           $ref: '#/components/schemas/image'
       'video/mpeg':
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/video'
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I address the issue of the headers being different for each content type too? I don't think I can use discriminators to resolve that?

Comment: Is it custom headers that differ, or just content-type and 'standard' HTTP headers?

Comment: Just the standard `content-type` header.

Comment: You don't need to include content-type in your response headers, that is implied by the mediatype object keys.